# Update database with Json API data on interval ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get temperature readings from a raspberry pi API once every 5 minutes.

Currently, when I refresh my homepage, it calls the API for each of my temperature sensors. It takes about 3 seconds for the page to load, which I am okay with, but would rather have some sort of background task that runs every 5 minutes and saves the data from the API call to my database. This way I have a nice log of the temperatures and can see variations.

This is what I want to run every 5 minutes. I don't have much experience with API's so I' not certain what the best way to accomplish this would be (PS: this is meant to run either on linux or a second raspberry pi)

```
foreach (var sensor in TempSensors) //for each one sensor get a reading from the api and save it
{
    var cookieName = api.CookieName;
    var cookieString = api.Cookie;
    var url = "apiurl";
    var baseAddress = new Uri(url);
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
    {
       var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/api/" + sensorId + "/read")                      
       message.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");

       cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new Cookie(cookieName, cookieString));
       HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(message.RequestUri); // call the api and get the reading

       if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
       {
          var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          TempReading tr = new TempReading(); // make a new reading
          tr.TempSensorId = sensorId.ToString(); //set its sensor id to the current sensor id     
          tr.TempReadingDate = DateTime.Now; // set the read time to right now
          tr.Value = content.ToString(); // write the reading to a string
          await Create(tr); //add it to the db                            
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider using the asp.net core background service to achieve your requirement. The background service could run when the application started or started every 5 minutes.

You could store something into a localstorage like redis or else. Then inside this background service you could read it and store it.

More details about how to use asp.net core background service, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply @Brando , I actually decided to just use quartz to startup a recurring task at startup and its working great. I started to go with the Service worker route, but it seemed to be quite a bit more effort than just using the Quartz.Net package.